# What is the difference between tf.keras.model and tf.keras.sequential?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In some `tf. keras` tutorials, I've seen them instantiated their model class like this:

`model = tf.keras.Sequential()`

While in some places, they use something like this:

`model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)`

But seeing here in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model), they do seem the same, but I am not sure nor is it explicitly mentioned. What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two class API to define a model in `tf. keras`. According to the doc

- [`Sequential class`](https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/): Sequential groups a linear stack of layers into a `tf. keras.Model`.
- [`Model class`](https://keras.io/api/models/model/): `Model` group's layers into an object with training and inference features.

---

An `Sequential` model is the simplest type of model, a linear stack of layers. But there are some flaws in using the `sequential` model API, it's limited in certain points. We can't build complex networks such as multi-input or multi-output networks using this API.

But using [`Model class`](https://keras.io/api/models/model/), we can instantiate a Model with the **Functional API** (and also with **Subclassing the Model class**) that allows us to create arbitrary graphs of layers. From this, we can get more flexibility and easily define models where each layer can connect not just with the previous and next layers but also share feature information with other layers in the model, for example, model-like `ResNet`, `EfficientNet`.

In fact, most of the SOTA model that you can get from `tf.keras.applications` is basically implemented using the **Functional API**. However, in subclassing API, we define our layers in `__init__` and we implement the model's forward pass in the `call` method.

Generally speaking, all the model definitions using Sequential API, can be achieved in Functional API or Model Subclassing API. And in Functional API or Model Subclassing API, we can create complex layers that not possible to achieve in Sequential API. If you wondering which one to choose, the answer is, it totally depends on your need. However, check out the following blog post where we have discussed the various model strategies in `tf. keras` with more examples. [Model Sub-Classing and Custom Training Loop from Scratch in TensorFlow 2](https://towardsdatascience.com/model-sub-classing-and-custom-training-loop-from-scratch-in-tensorflow-2-cc1d4f10fb4e)

Answer (score 0):

It's because they are from different versions of tensorflow. According to the documentation (TensorFlow 2.0), [tf.keras.Sequential](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) is the most recent way of calling the function. If you go to the documentation, and click on "View aliases", you can see the different aliases used in older version of Tensorflow for that function.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. But I think you need to add more info on this. And I think that's why people didn't understand your answer properly.

Comment: @M.Innat thx for your feedback, I'll add some more info