What is the difference between tf.keras.models.Sequential() and tf.keras.Sequential()?
I have just started building neural networks with tensorflow and different online resources have different ways of creating them. One thing I have noticed is how the sequential API is implemented. Some use tf.keras.Sequential() while others use tf.keras.models.Sequential()? Can anyone tell me the difference and when to use one over the other?
I have tried using them both in this mode but they both provide good results.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)


they both reffering to <class 'keras.src.models.sequential.Sequential'> So it is the same class.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879748/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-model-and-tf-keras-sequential

Here are several ways how to analyse functions and classes, and check their origins, and how they were imported.
# tensorflow == 2.16.1
# keras == 3.3.3

import tensorflow as tf

# let's analyse both classes
obj1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential
obj2 = tf.keras.Sequential

# we can check their ids - if the ids are the same than it is the same object
print (id(obj1)) # 13009365072
print (id(obj2)) # 13009365072

# this will print information about class origin
print (tf.keras.models.Sequential) 
# <class 'keras.src.models.sequential.Sequential'>

print (tf.keras.Sequential)
# <class 'keras.src.models.sequential.Sequential'>

Thus concluding - there is no difference between two classes. It is possible that there was a difference in previous TF or Keras versions, but in the latest packages both point to the same class. I would advise to use tf.keras.Sequential just because it is more convenient to print.
And Sequential class is actually a child of keras.Model class. You can check this inside keras code https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v3.3.3/keras/src/models/sequential.py#L17-L349
